# Unrolling and forwarding arrays

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having trouble unrolling and forwarding a parameter pack of std::arrays to another function

Suppose we have a function that takes a single std::array and I want to unroll it and pass it as an argument to some other function I can do so by doing this:

```
template<typename T, typename...Ts>
void other_function(T, Ts...) { /* Do stuff with Ts */ }

template<typename T, size_t Size, size_t... I>
void forward_array(std::array<T, Size>& array_arg, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
   other_function(array_arg[I]...);
// for Size == 3 let's say we get the same thing as we would write
// other_function(array_arg[0], array_arg[1], array_arg[2]
// I skipped the std::forward
}
```

Now let's say we have a function that does this same thing, but it takes multiple arrays that can be of different size.

```
template<typename T, size_t... Sizes /*, size_t... I_Sequence0, size_t... I_Sequence1, ... I_SequenceN */>
void forward_many_arrays(std::array<T, Sizes>&... array_args /*, ???*/)
{
  other_func( /* ??? */);
}
```

I want to unfold each array_arg and pass it to other_func, but how do I do that exactly here?. We would need a way to index into each array arg.

In my actual program, I have a class that has a member std::array of std::reference_wrapper which is not default constructable and I'm trying to provide an alternative constructor for that class that takes any number of arrays&, where the sum of their sizes matches the member array size and delegate it to the explicit constructor that takes T references, but I'm kind of stuck cause I don't know how to handle the unrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a "generic" getter

```
template <std::size_t I, typename Container, typename ... Containers>
decltype(auto) get(Container&& container, Containers&&...containers)
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Container>>;
    if constexpr (I < size) {
        return container[I];
    } else {
        return get<I - size>(containers...);
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
template <typename...Ts>
void other_function(Ts... ts) { ((std::cout << ts << " "), ...); }

template<typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
void forward_many_arrays(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&...ts)
{
  other_function(get<Is>(ts...)...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
void forward_many_arrays(Ts&&...ts)
{
  forward_many_arrays(std::make_index_sequence<(std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Ts>> + ...)>(), ts...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04483afbbc6d8bb3)

Answer (score 0):

An implementation based on simple recursion:

```
template<std::size_t n, class Fn, class T, class... Ts>
void apply_all_impl(Fn fn, T& t, Ts&... ts) {
    if constexpr (n == 0)
        fn(t, ts...);
    else
        std::apply([&](auto&... args) {
            apply_all_impl<n - 1>(fn, ts..., args...);
        }, t);
}

template<class Fn, class... Ts>
void apply_all(Fn fn, Ts&... ts) {
    apply_all_impl<sizeof...(Ts)>(fn, ts...);
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr1{1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 4> arr2{4, 5, 6, 7};

auto print_all = [](auto... ts) { (std::cout << ... << ts); };
apply_all(print_all, arr1, arr2);    // Output: 1234567
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/he5E8n)